# CRM 4 entity["name"] = "New value";

Tags: dynamics-crm

How do I update en entity for example:  updateEntity["name"] = ":"... I don't understand how i should work with images (pre/post) and "New Steps" pre/post. Please give me some guidlines how I update an entity. Everyting seems to be fine exept the last step... how to update an entity with some value (string). thanks... Fred 
Whats wrong with the code below???

```
 // Obtain the target business entity from the input parmameters
                DynamicEntity entity = (DynamicEntity)context.PreEntityImages["PreServiceMobile"];// context.InputParameters.Properties["Target"];
                DynamicEntity updateEntity = (DynamicEntity)context.InputParameters.Properties["Target"];

                            updateEntity["name"] = "value";
```

Comment: Make sure that you are also providing the record's ID when updating. The SDK documentation may be of some help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151102.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can only set values in the input entity during a pre stage plugin. In a post stage plugin, the entity has already been saved. If you need to update the entity in a post stage, you need to call CrmService.Update(entity)